# capture text between similar start-end blocks and store result in separate files

Tags: python, perl, sed, awk, grep

I have a large text file running into millions of lines.Between all these lines,there are a blocks of data as follows:

```
#Start of activity on <hostname>
....
....
....
....
#End of activity on <hostname>
```

Between each data block,there are lots of lines of junk data that I am not interested in.The above shown block of data appears randomly in the large text file.What I want to do is to move each block of data into separate file with the hostname tag in the block as the filename.
Also,at the end of the operation,the large file should have only the junk lines and should be devoid of any blocks.

What i currently have is this :

```
awk '/Start\sof\sactivity\son/{f=1;s="FILE"++i;next}/End\sof\sactivity\son/{f=0; close(s)}f{print > s}' bigfile
```

But it does not sort it into files with the filename as the hostname and neither does it delete the selected lines.
Any way this can be done using perl,awk,sed,grep or python ?

Edit:

For Jaypal ..The hostname is now in the beginning and only in the starting sentence of the block..The block is as follows:

```
SGSGSINCQ14FWR52B#start of activity
........
........
........
#end of activity
```

Comment: whoever down voted this,can I atleast know the reason for it ??Hit and run downvotes are just not cool !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with `awk`:

```
awk '/^#Start/{f=$NF;next}   /^#End/{f="";next}   {if(f){print >f}else print}' yourfile > junk
```

So, when we see `#Start` we pick up the last field (i.e. hostname) as `f` which we will use as the filename. When we see `#End` we will clear the filename. On all other lines, if the filename has been set (i.e. we are in a useful data block) we write to the named file `f`, and if not, we write to stdout which is redirected into a file called "junk"

If you have spaces, you do not need to esacpe them in `awk`:

```
echo "hi with a space" | awk '/hi with/'
hi with a space

echo "hi with a space" | awk '/hi there/'
```

If your hostname moves from the end of the `Start of activity` line to the beginning, the awk will change like this:

```
echo "hostname Start of activity" | awk '/Start of activity/{print $1}'
hostname
```

i.e. the hostname will be in $1, but we are still looking for `Start of activity` in the line somewhere.

Then the overall answer would become:

```
awk '/Start of activty/{f=$1;next}   /End of activity/{f="";next}   {if(f){print >f}else print}' yourfile > junk
```

Comment: Phew! Those speed-typing lessons really paid off :-) Glad to be of help.

Comment: mark..i had a few more doubts..1> is a \s required to escape whitespaces in the regex..2> if my starting block changes to <hostname> start of activity ..what will change in the awk statement ?

Comment: i am assuming for 2> $NF becomes just NF

Comment: @Amistad I believe `\s` to match whitespace was introduced in newer versions of `gnu awk` (probably 4 and greater). My `gnu awk` version 3.1.5 does not support it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (re-using most of your existing code):

```
awk '
/Start *of *activity *on/ {f=1; s=$NF; next}
/End *of *activity *on/   {f=0; close(s); next}
f{print > s; next}1
' bigfile > trunc_bigfile
```

- You were setting the filename to "FILE" and not on hostname. Using `$NF` we are saving the entries in hostname. If your hostname includes `<>` characters, use `sub()` or `gsub()` to remove them before assigning it to variable.
- The bigfile will never get updated, well unless you have `gawk 4.1` which supports in-file changes. We redirect the output of whats left in the file to STDOUT and using `>` we redirect STDOUT to `trunc_bigfile`.
- Other change I made was, at the End of block, use `next` to avoid getting that printed in the trucated big fil and using `1` to print all other lines outside of this block.

**Update:**

If the Start block has the hostname in random order then you can iterate over that line and capture the one that matches it (using a regex, I used upper case characters and digits based on the sample line you added to your question).:

```
/Start *of *activity *on/{f=1;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/[[:upper:][:digit:]]+/);{s=$i};next}
/End *of *activity *on/{f=0; close(s);next}
f{print > s;next}1
' bigfile > trunc_bigfile
```

Comment: jaypal..that worked..thanks..i though had a question..what if my starting block is <hostname> start of activity..i am assuming $NF will not work then..what is the alternative for that ?

Comment: @Amistad Is your hostname an IP address or Domain name? Can you post a sample like of actual data. You'll need to iterate over that line and find the one that is hostname and assign it to a variable. Something like - `/Start *of *activity *on/{f=1;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/\</);{s=$NF};next}`. Just put in a pattern that resembles your `hostname`.

Comment: @Amistad Check the updated solution. If your hostname is of specific pattern (All Upper Case Letters and Digits Only) then this should work just fine.